# Re: Transpose data using Linq

Tags: linq

I have a table, in the following format,

### |BallotNo |  City  |   CandidateNo  |    Votes

### |Box1    |   AA   |   Cand1        |     1200

### |Box1    |  AA    |   Cand2         |    1500

### |Box2    |  BB    |   Cand1         |    2500

### |Box2    |  BB    |   Cand2         |    3600

uing linq, I want to a get a result in the format

### |Box1 |AA  |Cand1   |1200  |Cand2 |1500

### |Box2  |BB  |Cand1   |2500  |Cand2 |3600

Thanks

Comment: What type the *table* really is? Is it `DataTable`, `List<CustomClass>`, database table? And what have you tried already?

Comment: That is not a transpose... perhaps you mean transform.

Comment: Maybe. Either way, can someone please provide a code sample to achieve that. I need to create a query very urgently. Thanks

Comment: This is a site where people help other people to understand certain things, not to write some code for free. You must at least show us what have you tried.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a grouping option.

As I have understood, you need to group by `City` row, it is pretty easy, see the http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534492.aspx link on how to use the `GroupBy` extension method.